# How does one access the folder "LocalCache" in a WinRT app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Using C# for WinRT how does one access the app data folder "LocalCache" ?

From the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx
I can see that under App data storage there is this description, "localcache Persistent data that exists only on the current device.", but I have yet to find a way to access the directory using the limitations of WinRT.

I wan't to put a sqlite file in there that will survive later installs of our WinRT app.

I can use

```
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path
```

to get to the LocalState folder, but I have yet to find something like

```
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalCache.Path
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LocalCache folder is only on Windows Phone 8.1; didn't make it into Windows 8.1. It's unfortunate that the docs don't state that clearly. Just use LocalState instead, as the cloud backup that the docs mention is also phone-only at present.